# WebSocket Exception C#

Tags: c#

i am getting following message when i am trying to read data from WebSocket Stream using a buffer.

The message is as follows:

> The Buffer type '96' is invalid. Valid Buffer types are : 'Close',
>   'BinaryFragment', 'BinaryMessage', 'UTF8Fragment', 'UTF8Message'

Following is the snippet what i am trying to do:

```
var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
result = await this.ws.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer.Array), CancellationToken.None);
```

Please suggest a solution.

Thanks in Advance

Ajay

Comment: Are you sure the sending side is using the WebSocket protocol?

Comment: Yes i am sure that i am using WebSocket Protocol, Because when i get the type of Exception. It says that it is from System.Net.WebSocketClient

Comment: My question is about the *other* side of the connection, not your code.

Comment: I also am getting this error; @Ajay did you resolve it? My error surfaces on the SignalR client.